# Is there any way to improve xamarin.android ui performance with background image

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

This is a problem that I've been faced with for quite some time now and I can't seem to find a solution (besides removing the background, which is not an option right now), I have tried the two solutions that I've come across and they don't make a significant difference:

- I tried adding the 'drawable-nodpi' folder and putting the background image there.
- I tried adding the background image to all the drawable folders

None of the above make much of a difference and the background image is roughly 200KB.

Answer (score 0):

When you say background you mean background image that takes the whole screen ?

Do you respect this ? :

```
xxxhdpi: 1280x1920 px
xxhdpi: 960x1600 px
xhdpi: 640x960 px
hdpi: 480x800 px
mdpi: 320x480 px
ldpi: 240x320 px
```

And how do you set your background ? Like this ? :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@mipmap/background"></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The dimensions you set are almost exactly the same as the ones I set, so yes I respect that :). The way you set the background though is different:

 - I'm using xaml for my layout not .axml
 - I used a xcml's Grid Layout instead of the relative layout that you're using

Comment: @CliftonSteenkamp Sorry I didn't see you were on .forms I thought it was .droid ! My bad really sorry. Have you tried 9-patch images ?

Comment: No I haven't tried it, but considering the fact that I've already tried the 'drawable-nodpi' method which does not scale the image at all, meaning less processing to be done by the device, I don't see how 9-patch images will benefit me, based on what I've read about it so far.

Comment: And it happens with all kind of images ? Maybe this is the limit of Xamarin.Forms ... the perfs aren't as good as native. Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: So much for trying to go hybrid. there's only one image format I use and thats .png images. Thanks for trying though Yohan, much appreciated!